# How to read a CSV column as a string in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I wrote code with pandas in order to pass in a CSV and retrieve a column, and then I have more code that is supposed to split the data using the re library, but it throws an error stating "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object."

I believe I just need to convert the CSV into a string before running re on it, but I can't figure out how.

The column in the CSV has data which look like: 'HB1.A1D62no.0016, HB31.N33NO.89, HB 54 .N338'

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('HB_Lib.csv', delimiter = ',')
s = [data[['Call Number']]]

import re

pattern = r"(^[a-z]+)\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)"
print(list(map("".join, [re.findall(pattern, part, flags=re.I)[0] for part in s])))
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:/Python/test2.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(list(map("".join, [re.findall(pattern, part, flags=re.I)[0] for part in s])))

  File "C:/Python/test2.py", line 8, in <listcomp>
    print(list(map("".join, [re.findall(pattern, part, flags=re.I)[0] for part in s])))

  File "C:\Python37\lib\re.py", line 223, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: Can you provide the traceback please

Comment: Your issue may be in that you have the extra brackets around `[data[['Call Number']]]` it should probably be `data['Call Number']`

Comment: Yes sir. I added the traceback

Comment: What does this csv look like btw?

Comment: @jab taking the double brackets and the external brackets out ended up fixing the problem! (I had previously tried one or the other to no avail.) Thank you, sir.

Answer (score 0):

```
data['Call Number'] = data['Call Number'].astype(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the first thing you should do is to remove the external square brakets when declaring s.

So, obtaining something like:

```
a = data[['something']]
```

Comment: That combined with removing the double brackets fixed my issue. Thanks!

Comment: @Jab this was the soluzion to the problem, so it was the answer. We are here to help people, not to gain points.

Comment: In that case you should have written a comment and voted to close the question as a typographical error (or flag for closure in comments).